# How to configure an image CDN in AWS, pointing to third-party images urls?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I want to use in my website images taken from amazon that have a url like this:

https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71dncPbANKL._AC_SX466_.jpg

I'd like to have something like this (for SEO purposes):

https://www.example.com/img?src=https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71dncPbANKL._AC_SX466_.jpg

how can I have this result using AWS resources?

I've tried to configure Cloud Front, but I can't find how to specify an external source like https://m.media-amazon.com/, it seems I can use only aws storage and aws services as source.

Comment: I am suspicious of the mywebsite.com page you link to - it runs some javascript code, which I don't know what it does. Can you include in your question something neutral, like `https://www.example.com/img?src=https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71dncPbANKL._AC_SX466_.jpg&subid1=20230226-0027-0977-bc66-96bff176c28e` instead?

Comment: Of course done immediately ... I never imagined that there really was a site with that url